# I cannot increase the throughput to the number I want

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing, throughput

I am trying to stress test my server.
To do so I am using Jmeter and here is my set up:

I use 
[my Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWP9Z.png)

```
Thread: 1000
schedule for 3 mins
```

So as you see I keep going with 1000 thread for a period of 3 mins.
But when I look at the throughput I only get around 230 per second

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0vn5.png)

So what should I do to increase the through put to for example 1000000 per second? How come increasing the thread which I assume means more load does not increase throughput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

Throughput explicitly relies on the application response time. Looking into your results, the average response time is 3.5 seconds therefore you will not get more than 1000 / 3.5 = 285 requests per second

Theoretically you could use [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination, this way JMeter will kick off extra threads if the current amount is not enough to reach/maintain the desired throughput, however looking into 8.5% error rate and maximum response time for your application > 2 minutes my expectation is that you will not be able to get more throughput because most probably your application is overloaded and cannot respond faster.

Answer (score 0):

Throughput measures the number of transactions or requests that can be made in a given period of time. basically, it lists the number of requests server managed to serve in a given time period. Throughput value depends on lot of factors and maybe your application under test not able to cater the expected load.
So with 1000 threads, you can't expect a 1000 throughput.

It's up to you to find out how much throughput your application can handle. For that maybe you need to do different optimizations on your side like optimize your script, distribute load via JMeter execution, increase theard count,...etc